# How can one restrict keyboard layout for specific applications, such as terminal emulator?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm not a native English speaker and use my native language most of the time.

E.G. when I type in my password in my screen saver, authentication fails as my keyboard layout has been set to my native language instead of English (when I surf the Web, I use my mother tongue almost everywhere).

Also, it's annoying when I'm trying to launch a terminal emulator and perform something, say, ssh access or something else, because if I forget to switch my keyboard layout from what was set in the browser, I misspell a command in the terminal window!

Yes, I know, that one may switch to a "per-application" keyboard layout control. But this is NOT what I want. My question is how can one use all the applications the usual way (need to switch between layouts) except some arbitrary applications, which don't need any typing in my native language (terminal, screensaver password prompt, Synaptic, etc...), because I assume that I will never want to type in something in my native language, say, in the terminal emulator.

So, is there some way to **restrict** KB layout to *English* on a per-application basis?

P.S. Also, it would be nice if I could restrict layout to Engilsh for some in-browser elements, say, address bar. What if I know exactly that I will never want to type in anything except WWW addresses there? Can I restrict the input language?